# What's the point of "plt.figure"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*t)

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'bo', t2, f(t2), 'k')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t2, np.cos(2*np.pi*t2), 'r--')
plt.show()
```

According to offical Matplotlib document(https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure)
A figure function will

> "If num is provided, and a figure with this id already exists, make it
>   active, and returns a reference to it. "

I tried do the above on my Ipython without plt.figure, but it showed the two required pictures still.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three cases where `plt.figure` is useful:

1. **Obtaining a handle to a figure.**  In many cases it is useful to have a handle to a figure, i.e. a variable to store the `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instance in, such that it can be used later on. Example:

   ```
   fig = plt.figure()
   #... other code
   fig.autofmt_xdate()
   ```
2. **Set figure parameters.**  An option to set some of the parameters for the figure is to supply them as arguments to `plt.figure`, e.g.

   ```
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,7), dpi=144)
   ```
3. **Create several figures.** In order to create several figures in the same script, `plt.figure` can be used. Example:

   ```
   plt.figure()      # create a figure
   plt.plot([1,2,3])
   plt.figure()      # create another figure
   plt.plot([4,5,6]) # successive commands are plotted to the new figure
   ```

In many other cases, there would not actually be any need to use `plt.figure`. Using the pyplot interface, a call to any plotting command is sufficient to create a figure and you can always obtain a handle to the current figure with `plt.gcf()`.

From another perspective it is often desired not only to have a handle to the figure but also to an axes to plot to. In such cases, the use  of `plt.subplots` is more favorable, `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`.

Comment: Ok, I created a figure(or say, several figures). Now, how do I refer or choose a particular figure to show my plot/image onto? Is there a no.? Or, all of it just happens sequentially in order, and you need to remember that?

Answer (score 6):

The `plt.figure` gives you a new figure, and depending on the given argument it opens a new figure or not. Compare:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```

to

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```

to

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
```

You will see that the first example is equal to the third, because you retrieve the same figure handle with the second `plt.figure(1)` call in the third example.